# Rake task rails:upgrade:check is not working on windows. Rails 3 Upgrade problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, popen

Is there any solution to solve the problem of rake task rails:upgrade:check on windows ?

Comment: you'll have to be more specific

Comment: yeah we need the full backtrace on this one (run rake with --trace or --backtrace or something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve out this problem i have install this gems.

```
gem install POpen4 -v 0.1.4
gem install win32-open3
gem install rak
```

Then modify rails_upgrade plugin file.

```
vendor/rails_upgrade/lib/application_checker.rb
```

In that file replace find_with_rake method with this lines .

```
def find_with_rak(text, where, double_quote)
    value = ""
    %x[rak '#{Regexp.escape(text)}' #{where}].each do |f|
      value << f
    end
    #        POpen4.popen4("rak --nogroup -l '#{Regexp.escape(text)}' #{where}") do |stdin, stdout, stderr|
    #          value = stdout.read
    #        end
    value
end
```

This works for me ... May be this one help someone to upgrade to rails 3 on windows ..